# Override ServiceCollection in middleware

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am registering a service in Startup.cs

```
services
    .AddRandomComponent(options =>
            {
                config.DisableCoolFeature();
            });
```

Method AddSomeComponent

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static RandomComponent AddRandomComponent(this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<Config> setupSettings = null)
    {
        services
            .AddOptions<Config>()
            .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.BindUISettings(settings);
                setupSettings?.Invoke(settings);
            });

        services.TryAddSingleton<LoggingService>();

        return new RandomComponent (services);
    }
}
```

Now I have a need that on specific request, enable `CoolFeature`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried this, but the "item" is null.

```
public class RandomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RandomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = context.RequestServices;

        var item = serviceProvider.GetService<RandomComponent>();

        if (context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("coolFeature", out var isCoolFeature))
        {
            // Override service collection 
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Option pattern with DI.

First, create an options class:

```cs
public class MyCustomMiddlewareOptions
{
    public bool DisableCoolFeature { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Then inject the options instance in the middleware's constructor:

```cs
public class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    private readonly MyCustomMiddlewareOptions options;

    public MyCustomMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<MyCustomMiddlewareOptions> options)
    {
        this.options = options.Value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (!options.DisableCoolFeature ||
            httpContext.Request.Query.Any(query =>
                query.Key == "coolFeature" && query.Value == "true"))
        {
            // cool feature is enabled by config or forced by query string
        }

        await next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

The framework can already load the values from the configuration providers, but you might want to override that configuration. Add a delegate parameter in your extensions file and configure the options with it:

```cs
public static class MyCustomMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyCustomMiddleware(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<MyCustomMiddlewareOptions> configurationOptions)
    {
        return services.Configure(configurationOptions);
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomMiddleware(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Finally, setup your pipeline:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMyCustomMiddleware(options =>
{
    options.DisableCoolFeature = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseMyCustomMiddleware();

await app.RunAsync();
```

---

**References:**

- You can read more about different options patterns available to lib authors here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors